# How to save mpesa transaction in my django app

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, mpesa

I am currently working on a django app where I can be able to see and save all transaction made via my till number... No stk push just to be able to see and save all transaction done to that till number... Is there a way I  can achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two tables i.e. one for the transaction request (with acknowledgment response from safaricom) and the other for transaction response (response returned from safaricom via your implemented callback).